# How do I set the colour of a cell in a table on error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am validating each cell in a table and want to colour a cell red if there is an error. This what I have tried (no error on the console and the cell is not red when an error is returned):

css:

```
.redBg {background: red !important;}
```

javascript and jQuery:

```js
//Return each element
var row = 0;
var column = 0;
$("#wrapper tr").each(function() {
  row++;
  column = 0;
  if (row > 1) {
    $('td', this).each(function() {
      column++;
      if (!$(this).text().replace(/\s/g, '').length) {
        alert("Row " + row + " column " + column + " only containes whitespace (i.e., empty, spaces, tabs or line breaks).");
      } else {
        if (column == 3) {
          var dateFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
          if (!moment($(this).text(), dateFormat).isValid()) {
            alert("Row " + row + " DOB does not contain a valid date.");
            $('td', this).addClass('redBg');
          }
        }
        if (column == 4) {
          if (isNaN($(this).text())) {
            alert("Row " + row + " Scout Number must be numeric. " + $(this).text());
            $('td', this).addClass('redBg');
          }
        }
        if (column == 5) {
          var dateFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
          if (!moment($(this).text(), dateFormat).isValid()) {
            alert("Row " + row + " Joining Date does not contain a valid date.");
            $('td', this).addClass('redBg');
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }
})
```

I have also tried replacing

```
$('td', this).addClass('redBg');
```

with

```
$(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").css("background-color", red);
```

Comment: And do you see any of the alerts?

Comment: *if (row > 1)* will not work the first time because your starting value is zero. Without your HTML it is not possible to tell if this is really causing the issue.

Comment: Yes all alerts are shown. I start with row > 1 to exclude the headers on the input.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) documentation about **strict parsing**:

> As of version 2.3.0, you may specify a **boolean for the last argument** to make Moment use **strict parsing**. Strict parsing requires that the format and input match exactly, including delimeters.
>
> `moment('It is 2012-05-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD').isValid();       // true`
> `moment('It is 2012-05-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid(); // false`
> `moment('2012-05-25',       'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid(); // true`
> `moment('2012.05.25',       'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid(); // false`

Also, when **inside** `$('td', this).each(` function, by doing `$('td', this)` is just looking for a TD inside a TD, not what you want.

Also, use `<tbody>` and `'tbody'` as your selector (to skip the thead's TR)

Also, instead of doing

```
if ( Boolean ) {
  if ( Boolean ) {
  }
}
```

you can simply do:

```
if(Boolean && Boolean) {
}
```

Here you go:

```js
var dateFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY'; // You need this set only once

$("#wrapper tbody tr").each(function() {
  var row = $(this).index() + 1; // +1 since index is 0 based

  $('td', this).each(function() {
    var $col = $(this);
    var col = $col.index() + 1;
    var text = $.trim($col.text()); // GET TRIMMED TEXT
    var err = ""; // Empty error

    if (text.length === 0)
      err += `Row ${row} column ${col} only containes whitespace (i.e., empty, spaces, tabs or line breaks).\n`

    if (col === 3 && !moment(text, dateFormat, true).isValid())
      err += `Row ${row} DOB does not contain a valid date.`;

    if (col === 4 && isNaN(text))
      err += `Row ${row} Scout Number must be numeric. ${text}`;

    if (col === 5 && !moment(text, dateFormat, true).isValid())
      err += `Row ${row} Joining Date does not contain a valid date.`;

    if (err) {
      $(this).addClass('redBg');
      alert(err);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.redBg {
  background: red!important;
}
```

```html
<table id="wrapper">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>?</th>
      <th>DOB</th>
      <th>Scout num.</th>
      <th>Joined</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <td>#1</td>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>444</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```